# Update fields from string in JQ

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a bash `$string` containing the values: `abc,def` and a *file.json* looking like this:

```json
[
  {
    "loc": "51.12345, 12.12345",
    "city": "CityName1"
  },
  {
    "loc": "65.12345, 15.12345",
    "city": "CityName2"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to update the city field with the values from the string to get this result:

```json
[
  {
    "loc": "51.12345, 12.12345",
    "city": "abc"
  },
  {
    "loc": "65.12345, 15.12345",
    "city": "def"
  }
]
```

I'm trying this code but it doesn't work, any suggestions?

```
  string="abc,def"; jq --arg variable "$string" '.city = $string' file.json
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for something like this:

```
$ string=abc,def
$ jq --arg cities "$string" '[., ($cities / ",")] | transpose | map(.[0] + {city: .[1]})' file.json
[
  {
    "loc": "51.12345, 12.12345",
    "city": "abc"
  },
  {
    "loc": "65.12345, 15.12345",
    "city": "def"
  }
]
$
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with jq version 1.4:
error: transpose is not defined
[., ($cities / ",")] | transpose | map(.[0] + {city: .[1]}) 1 compile error

Comment: @maria Update jq or refer to pmf's answer

Comment: … or add the def of transpose to your program.

Answer (score 1):

With [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs):

```
> var json =   [
...     {
...       "loc": "51.12345, 12.12345",
...       "city": "CityName1"
...     },
...     {
...       "loc": "65.12345, 15.12345",
...       "city": "CityName2"
...     }
...   ]
> var c = 0
> ["abc", "def"].forEach(n => json[c++].city = n)
> console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, 4))
[
    {
        "loc": "51.12345, 12.12345",
        "city": "abc"
    },
    {
        "loc": "65.12345, 15.12345",
        "city": "def"
    }
]
```

From a script :

```
#!/bin/bash

node<<EOF | sponge file.json
var json = $(< file.json)
var c = 0;
["abc", "def"].forEach(n => json[c++].city = n)
console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, 4))
EOF
```

output file:

```
[
    {
        "loc": "51.12345, 12.12345",
        "city": "abc"
    },
    {
        "loc": "65.12345, 15.12345",
        "city": "def"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `reduce` would be another way. Same lengths provided, it allows iterating over the entries along with their indices, which can then be used to access the input array.

```bash
string="abc,def"
jq --arg var "$string" '
  reduce ($var / "," | to_entries)[] as {$key, $value} (.;
    .[$key].city = $value
  )
'
```

> I'm getting an error with jq version 1.4

To make this approach compatible with jq 1.4, replace the variable destructuring with a plain variable, and access its parts later, e.g.

```bash
string="abc,def"
jq --arg var "$string" '
  reduce ($var / "," | to_entries)[] as $item (.;
    .[$item.key].city = $item.value
  )
'
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "loc": "51.12345, 12.12345",
    "city": "abc"
  },
  {
    "loc": "65.12345, 15.12345",
    "city": "def"
  }
]
```